# Unicode character encoding issue in Access

Tags: ms-access, jdbc

I stored Arabic data in MS Access database when I retrieve these data it is returned in question marks.
How can I solve this problem and how can I change MS Access encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Unicode characters from an Access database via JDBC-ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19192750/2144390).

Comment: Ok, Many Thanks Mr Gord for your help